# what does this step on the proof of lim $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The author defined $e:= \lim(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, let $x_n= \lim(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$

and then started proving $y_n=\lim \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} = e$, he first expanded $e:= \lim(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ by using the binomial theorem and showed $x_n \leq y_n \implies \lim x_n \leq \lim y_n$ as follows.

$$x_n= 1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!}\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{2}{n}\Big)...\Big(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\Big)$$
$$\leq 1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$$

And then to prove the other side he wrote

$$x_n \geq 1+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{2}{n}\Big)...\Big(1-\frac{k}{n}\Big)$$

Fix $m$. Then for any $n>m$, we have $x_n >y_m$...

#### My doubt is how did he concluded that $x_n >y_m$ after the last equation... kindly help

Comment: Each of the $(1-\frac in)$ are less than $1$. This means each term in the sum is less than $\frac{1}{k!}$ and that means $y_n \leq x_n$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Yes ... But in last line he said the other way

Comment: Note the change in index!

Answer (score 0):

You said the book already proved $\lim x_n$ is convergent so I will assume this.

If $n>m$, where $m$ is fixed, we sum more elements on $x_n$, hence:

$$x_n = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{2}{n}\Big)...\Big(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\Big) \geq$$

$$ 1+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{2}{n}\Big)...\Big(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\Big)$$

Because limit preserves order, we have:

$$\lim_n x_n\geq\lim_n \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{2}{n}\Big)...\Big(1-\frac{k}{n}\Big)\right)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}$$

Because our fixed $m$ is arbitrary, this holds for all $m$. But then, we have an upper bound independent of $m$ and:

$$\lim_n x_n \geq \lim_m \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{1}{k!}$$

Comment: $\lim_n \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)\Big(1-\frac{2}{n}\Big)...\Big(1-\frac{k}{n}\Big)\right)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k!}$  how are they equal?

Comment: Do you know that finite sum of terms whose limit exist is the sum of the limit of each term? Similarly, the limit of a product of terms whose limit exist is the product of the limits.

Comment: sorry... I just missed to see it using the algebra of convergent sequences... Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: But in my question he mentioned $x_n>y_m$. How's that?

Comment: I think it is not immediately clear $x_n>y_m$ if you don’t work with limits.